# DEM to TIN library

Tags: c++

I'm developing an application with C++ and i need to convert raster data (**DEM**) to Triangulated Irregular network (**TIN**), any library suggested ?

I tryed with *arcGIS* but I need Code in c++

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure whether there are existing C++ libraries that already implements this conversion.

But this can give you a rough idea of what would have to be implemented if this was to be done from scratch in C++ (with the STL and the CGAL library):

1. convert your raster data into a triangulated grid of elevated
   points (each DEM sample becomes a TIN vertex with x/y/z coordinates and the 4 neighboring samples in the DEM are connected via 2 TIN triangles). That's the easy part. Obviously this is a TIN, except that it's not irregular at all and probably contains too many samples.
2. remove redundant vertices from the TIN (one by one), and re-triangulate the hole that was just created. Repeat until satisfied. That's the difficult part. First, you need to have some criterion to measure how redundant a TIN vertex is (some measure of local flatness of the TIN for instance). The vertices should be ordered according to this criterion (read this as use a priority queue to order the vertices with this measure as the priority). When the most redundant vertex is removed, the corresponding hole has to be triangulated (you need to find the vertices along the border of the hole and triangulate the polygon) and the measure of redundancy of the neighboring vertices has to be updated. Finally, you obviously need to decide to stop this process at some point (have a minimum allowed redundancy).